# Looking to add functionality to more than one button in the same panel in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe

Here is the full code:

```
 public class HelloWorld implements ActionListener{
    private static JLabel label;
    private static JTextField usernameText;
    private static JLabel password;
    private static JPasswordField passwordText;
    private static JButton login;
    private static JLabel success;
    private static JButton Reset;
```

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String user = usernameText.getText();
            String password = passwordText.getText();
            System.out.println(user + "," + password);
            String command = e.getActionCommand();
```

```
        if(command.equals("Reset")){
            System.out.print("Hello");
```

I have
`String command = e.getActionCommand();`
inside my
`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {` 
above in in my public static main I have

```
reset = new JButton("reset");

reset.setBounds(85,170,100,25);

panel.add(reset);
```

where all my in my buttons, text fields, and labels have been created. I also have

```
if(command.equals("reset")){
```

in my `@Override` but when I click the reset button nothing happens.

Comment: I think you're missing: reset.setActionCommand("reset");

Comment: could you post the full class code? it's hard to get the full context from here

Comment: @pcalkins where do I put reset.setActionCommand

Comment: somewhere after new JButton("reset") and before "panel.add(reset)"  Check your case... ("Reset" or "reset") you've got it two ways above...

Comment: yes i changed it from a capital in one spelling to lowercase in the other to see if that affected anything

Comment: I don't see where you add the ActionListener to the buttons. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for a working demo. Download the demo code and make changes to that code. Your current code is wrong. You should NOT be using static variables.

Answer (score 0):

In actionPerformed do

```
if(e.getSoruce == buttonNmae) {
   // Your code

}
```

For example:

```
if(e.getSource == reset) {
  resetGame();

}
```